# How can I query nested model attributes through Waterline in MongoDB?

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm trying to do something like:

```
filter.or = [
  { name: { contains: q } },
  { "location.city": { contains: q } }
];
```

However it seems that "location.city", trying the MongoDB query language, is not working.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Share your entire model call and version info (sails, waterline & sails-mongo, because that works fine for me. I just tested the exact same query your showing above on some data I have in mongo via sails console and it works.

Comment: Okay, wait me some minutes and I will do it. Thanks for your response

Comment: Here is query I ran from a set of data I have on my site. I made sure the first OR would come up as false, so in order for the query to show data the sub-document query would have to come up true. . . and it did. It's basically the same as yours

Order.find({or:[{videoProgress:10000},{"charge.object":{contains:'charge'}}]}).exec(console.log)